# How to let user configure a file inside the war file

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, web-applications

There is an application, say myApp.war (developed using Spring MVC) that I give the users to deploy in their tomcat webapp folder. When the user starts tomcat, the war is exploded, and then I ask the user to go myApp/WEB-INF/classes/persistence.properties and ask him to edit just one property name (actually an HSQLDB path). Post that I ask the user to stop tomcat, delete the war file and start tomcat server again. And the application is up and running.

Although the users are not complaining, I believe there has to be a better way of doing this. For example when the users deploy wordpress or hudson and the first time they try to access the app. they are redirected to an install page where they do their basic configuration and they are up and running. How can I achieve it here.

Comment: Sorry, but the idea for the config path seems really bad to me. What happens if you (the user) redeploy the app? The file already exists before, right? If you changed any comment, hint, placeholder.. in this file it will be overridden on deploy and the user config is gone. It would be much better to take the config file out of the application container and place it somewhere more common (/opt, $HOME or anything like that)

Answer (score 1):

I have used JNDI to solve this very problem in the past. Here is a nice example to show you how to do this with Spring:

http://www.journaldev.com/2597/spring-datasource-jndi-with-tomcat-example

Comment: Thanks Jason, While the solution looks good, the average user may not be comfortable going and modifying the server.xml located in apache-tomcat/conf/.

Comment: I guess it depends on the user. If we are talking about devops then they would welcome this type of solution. Another way would be to have Jenkins ( CI system ) wired to do this sort of work; however, since we are talking about HSQLDB I got to think DevOPS type.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [JMX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/overview/index.html) which can allow on the fly configuration, or there is one [obix](http://sourceforge.net/projects/obix-framework/) framework

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this:

Use a relative path with [sysprops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html), like `${user.home}/path-to-hsqldb`. If the user runs tomcat as user "jim", it will look in `c:\users\jim\path-to-hsqldb` (Windows) or `/usr/jim/path-to-hsqldb` (Linux)

You might need to use Spring's `<context:property-placeholder/>` to enable this.